# Find the order of the pole and the residue of $f(x)=\frac{\cos z}{z^2}$ and $g(x)=\frac{e^z-1}{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, singularity

> Find the order of the pole and the residue of $$f(z)=\frac{\cos z}{z^2}$$ and $$g(z)=\frac{e^z-1}{z^2}$$

**What I said:**

$f(z)=\frac{\cos z}{z^2}$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0$. Then:
$Res(f,0)=-\sin(0)=0$. Can a residue be $0$?

For $g(z)$:
Taylor expand $\frac{e^z-1}{z^2}=1/z+1/2!+z/3!+z^2/4!...$ which implies that $1$ is the residue. What would be the order of this?

Comment: Let $\gamma(z) = 1+ {1 \over 2!} z + {1 \over 3!} z^2+\cdots$, which is analytic, then $\gamma(0) = 1$ and $g(z) = {\gamma(z) \over z}$, whence $g$ has a pole of order 1 at $z=0$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, so at $z=0$ is a pole of order $1$, the residue is $1$. If at $z=0$, a pole has order $1$, does it mean it has order $1$ for all $z$? Also, I know that holomorphic functions are analytic. Are analytic functions also holomorphic?

Comment: Analytic & holomorphic are the same.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your question ('order 1 for all $z$'). Poles occur at specific points and the order refers to the degree of the pols at that particular point.

Comment: thanks, it's clear now. Also Can a a residue be $0$, for the $f(z)$ case?

Comment: The residue is just the coefficient of ${ 1\over z}$ in the Laurent expansion. It can have any value. Why would zero be excluded? The residue of all analytic functions is zero at all points...

Comment: @copper.hat thanks a lot :)